# What is the intuition behind medians (and quartiles) being defined as the value of the $(n+1)/p$ th observation?

Tags: statistics, median

When calculating the median of an un-grouped distribution, we take the $(n+1)/2$ the value.

For quartiles it's $\text{I} \cdot (n+1)/4$.

For deciles it's $\text{I} \cdot (n+1)/10$.

What is the intuition behind the $1$ added to $n$? More generally, why do we find the midpoint of numbers $1$ to $n$ at $(n+1)/2$?

Comment: If you need to find the mid-point of a series $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots , n\}$, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ allows you to get it. If you have an odd number of cases, it’ll be the middle case. If you have an even number of cases, it’ll be halfway between the two cases on either side of the middle.

Comment: Because we want quantiles to be symmetric: if we reverse our sample (say, by changing sign of each element), the quantiles should remain the same. The reversal maps $k$th element into $(n+1-k)$th. E.g. $(n+1)/4$th element becomes $3(n+1)/4$th: 1st quartile becomes 3rd quartile, *just as expected*.